# Error message when Confirm Checkout and Send Mail SMTP [OpenCart]

Tags: php, email, smtp, opencart

I have installed and setting open cart on my localhost [XAMPP], opencart V 3.0.3.2,

The Issue is when Guest Checkout from Payment, it has error Like This

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
OK
<b>Warning</b>: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>D:\Master-After-Install\Xampp\htdocs\lat-open-cart\system\library\mail\mail.php</b> on line <b>77</b><b>Warning</b>: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>D:\Master-After-Install\Xampp\htdocs\lat-open-cart\system\library\mail\mail.php</b> on line <b>77</b><b>Warning</b>: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>D:\Master-After-Install\Xampp\htdocs\lat-open-cart\system\library\mail\mail.php</b> on line <b>77</b>{"redirect":"http:\/\/localhost\/lat-open-cart\/index.php?route=checkout\/success"}
```

I try to solve it But Still not Work, I connect it with my Email SMTP Port and I have check 3 times my SMTP is work.

Can Anyone Fix this Issue?

Comment: Are your website in a shared server? Sometimes they disabled all mail functions including SMTP, as well can you add your SMTP configuration?

Comment: hi @e-israel im still work on localhost. usually when i Use Php I can set it with phpmailer with gmail smtp or email hosting server. but this error make me confuses.

Comment: To use `mail()` function in localhost you must have a `Mail Exchange` service installed, do you have that one?

Comment: hi @e-israel ok i will try install mail exchane service like you say.

Comment: Hi, i have searched your advice, and I think that still  isnt my Issue, what I Want is, Localhost -> can use/ send email -> via SMTP Google, or My Hosting Mail Service. 

and it work well on my php script, but error inside this opencart. Any Advice again?

Comment: Maybe this can help you, there are many solutions, [Opencart forum](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=59012)